# How to use Drive API with credentials of a standard Google App Engine in Python 37?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I want to write a file in a Team Drive from a GAE (standard) in Python 37. I added its service account to my Team Drive members. But I cannot use the default App Engine Credentials to write.

I cannot use App Engine APIs because they are not available in GAE Standard for Python 37.

```
from google.auth import default
from googleapiclient import discovery
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseUpload

def upload_file_to_teamdrive(fd, file_name, team_drive_id, mime_type='application/text'):

        scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

        # How to get GAE Credentials ? 
        credentials, project = default(scopes=scopes)

        drive = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

        media = MediaIoBaseUpload(fd, mimetype=mime_type)

        drive.files().create(
            supportsTeamDrives=True,
            media_body=media,
            body={
                'parents': [team_drive_id],  # ID of the Team Drive,
                'name': file_name
            },
            fields='id'
        ).execute()
```

This code throw a 403 response:

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?supportsTeamDrives=true&fields=id&alt=json&uploadType=multipart returned "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."

What is the best way to write from GAE to Drive ? How my GAE could be authenticated with its service account ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The credentials exposed by the App Engine Environment can only authorize Google Cloud scopes, not any other Google API's scope like `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`.

You need to use a full service account key (ideally with KMS for security) to access those APIs.

You can have a look at the library I created and always use to connect to Google APIs [easygoogle](https://github.com/Fryuni/easygoogle)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, is it the easiest way to write to TeamDrive from AppEngine ? Have you got an example ?